# How to get React State update in different file to use SwitchNavigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm still pretty new to React Native and this may need a simple solution and/or I'm going about this completely wrong.

I want to create a terms and condition page. So in my `TermsAndCondition.js` I've created a `isAccepted = React.useState(false)` and then I import it to `App.js`.

When reloading `App.js` for the first time, it will have the state of `isAccepted = false`. My button works when changing the state to `isAccepted = true` But it doesn't update it in `App.js` to allow me to use the `"SwitchNavigator"` to switch to a different set of screens.

I just want to be able to have my terms and condition screen but by itself and not being part of a stack to go back. Is there a way to get `isAccepted` to be updated in another file or to get this same idea going?

Following my code.

`App.js`

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        {!isAccepted ? (
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Terms and Conditions"
              component={TermsAndConditions}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="mapListScreen" component={mapListScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="mapScreen1" component={mapScreen1} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

`TermsandCondition.js`

```
function TermsAndConditions() {
  const [isAccepted, setIsAccepted] = React.useState(false);
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(false);

  const handleAcceptInput = () => {
    setIsAccepted(!isAccepted);
  };

  const handleActiveInput = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Terms and conditions</Text>
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.tcContainer}
        onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
            handleActiveInput();
          }
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.tcP}>Some text</Text>
      </ScrollView>

      <TouchableOpacity
        disabled={!isActive}
        onPress={() => handleAcceptInput()}
        style={isActive ? styles.button : styles.buttonDisabled}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonLabel}>Accept</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
export default TermsAndConditions;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your state in your Stack Navigator like this you have to use React-Redux for this.